# Testcase name is not coming in TEST-TestSuite.xml file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, rest-assured

I am using TestNg framework to execute the test cases. I am planning to integrate Jenkins with Testrail. Jenkins reads the TEST-TestSuite.xml file and send details to testRail.

But Testcase name is not coming in TEST-TestSuite.xml file. Following is my testNg.xml to execute tests. I tried two or three types but still not working.

File1 :

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="External API regression Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="3">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="Regression"/>
        </run>
    </groups>

    <test name="Token Generation Test Cases">
        <classes>
            <class name="ai.test.api.testsuite.test">
                <methods>
                    <include name="verifyTokenResponseWithValidCredentials">
                        <parameter name="TestName" value="Verify Token Response with Valid Credentials"/>
                    </include>
                    <include name="verifyTokenWithInvalidCredentials">
                        <parameter name="TestName" value="Verify Token with Invalid Credentials"/>
                    </include>
                    <include name="verifyTokenWithoutUsername">
                        <parameter name="TestName" value="Verify Token Without Username"/>
                    </include>
                    <include name="verifyTokenWithoutXapi">
                        <parameter name="TestName" value="Verify Token Without Xapi"/>
                    </include>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

File2 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="External API regression Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="3">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="Regression"/>
        </run>
    </groups>

    <test name="Token Generation Test Cases">
        <classes>
            <class name="ai.test.api.testsuite.test">
                <methods>
                    <include name="verifyTokenResponseWithValidCredentials" description="Verify token response with valid credentials"/>
                    <include name="verifyTokenWithInvalidCredentials" description="Verify token response with invalid credentials"/>
                    <include name="verifyTokenWithoutUsername" description="Verify token response without username"/>
                    <include name="verifyTokenWithouttoken" description="Verify token response without xapi"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

How to get test name in "TEST-TestSuite.xml" file

Comment: <testcase name="" classname="ai.test.api.testsuite.test" time="6.797"/>

  <testcase name="" classname="ai.test.api.testsuite.test" time="0.371"/>

  <testcase name="" classname="ai.test.api.testsuite.test" time="0.505"/>

  <testcase name="" classname="ai.test.api.testsuite.test" time="0.481"/>


My TEST-TestSuite.xml file generated like this